# Git: checkout -b branchName <remote>/branchName (и правильно ли разрешаю конфликты ?)

Tags: git

На гитхабе создали pull request (merge с мастером), который вызвал десяток конфликтов. Я в первый раз столкнулся  с этим на практике, а опыта работы с этим нет.

Хотел бы понять, правильно ли я работаю с гитом для разрешения конфликтов, и также В процессе разрешения конфликтов, возникло несколько вопросов.

**Рабочий процесс**:

Изначально нахожусь в ветке `master`.

```
# забираю из репозитория последние изменения
git pull origin master

# создаю тестовую ветку, в которой буду разрешать конфликт при merge
git checkout -b feature/temp-branch

# получаю все ветки из репозитория
git fetch origin

# далее, создаю ветку, в которой будет копия состояния удаленной ветки
# (которую нужно сливать с мастером)
git checkout -b feature/conflict-features origin/conflict-features
```

после создания ветки `feature/conflict-features` - git выводит сообщение:

**Branch** `'feature/conflict-features'` **set up to track remote branch** `'conflict-features'` **from** `'origin'`.

Не понимаю, что происходит.. какая-то связь установлена, что это значит ? Такое происходит если создавать ветку от remote-ветки ?

Дальше, переключаюсь обратно на ветку `feature/temp-branch`, и пишу команду для мерджа:

```
git checkout - 
git merge feature/conflict-features
```

дальше, гит выдает конфликтные файлы, которые нужно разрешить.

Например я исправил пару конфликтов, очистил конфоль, и хочу понять, какие еще конфликты нужно разрешить - как мне это сделать ?

Подскажите пожалуйста, что делаю правильно, а что не правильно и почему ?

Comment: Зачем `git checkout -b feature/conflict-features origin/conflict-features` это? Я обычно делаю так: `git checkout -b feature/conflict-features`.

Comment: @hedgehogues чтобы в `feature/conflict-features` было состояние `origin/conflict-features`

Comment: Можно делать прямо в той же ветке, которую Вы мерджите.

Answer (score 0):

Я ни разу не видел подобного подхода. Думаю, что Ваша проблема в том, что Вы делаете команду:

```
git checkout -b feature/conflict-features origin/conflict-features
```

Зачем Вам ещё одна ветка?

Начало:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем решаете конфликт в этой ветке и туда подмёрдживаете мастер:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конфликты решены. Теперь обновляете пул-реквест в мастер:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Владелец репы принимает пул-реквест

---

## Update

Переключаемся на ветку с фичой Вашей:

```
git checkout feature
```

Делаем:

```
git merge master
```

Решаем конфликты:

```
git add .

git commit
```

Пушим ваши изменения в Вашу удалённую ветку:

```
git push origin feature
```

Посмотрите также, в сторону rebase. У него, по сравнению с merge, есть свои плюсы и минусы. Я обыно пользуюсь им.

Comment: "Зачем Вам ещё одна ветка?" так гитхаб рекомендует, если я правильно понял..
http://joxi.ru/BA07xO7iPQWbN2

Comment: спасибо большое за ответ, но честно говоря по схемам вообще не понял, что нужно делать и как правильно

Comment: @samiy-slavniy поправил